# Javascript audio not playing (soundboard?)

Tags: javascript, html

Posted some code earlier, and have tried to revamp it.. to no avail. The code below gives no errors, and I -think- (I am a complete newb) it should work, but I am not sure why it's not playing. I'm trying to make a soundboard for our D&D game. The code is a follows:

```
<html>
<body>
  <audio id="heroic" src="heroic.mp3"></audio>
  <button onClick="togglePlay()" id="heroicbutton">Heroic Battle Music</button>

<script>
//<!--Audio as variables-->
var audio1 = new Audio("heroic.mp3")
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay(){
if  (isPlaying = true){
  audio1.pause()
} else {
  audio1.play();
}
};
audio1.onplaying = function () {
  isPlaying = true;
}

audio1.onpause = function () {
  isPlaying = false;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The file 'heroic.mp3' is in the same folder, and no errors appear on chrome's developer tools. I am not sure why nothing is playing.

Comment: You have a mistake in your check in `togglePlay`, specifically: `if  (isPlaying = true){` you are making an assignment rather than comparison. Assignment always results in true. You need to use double equals to check for true.

Answer (score 0):

You have actually made a simple mistake here.
Inside the if you should have comparison '==' not assignment '='

```
if  (isPlaying == true){
```